# Deserialize from json string to list of dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization

I am passing array of json objects from ajax method.

```
                var FieldValue = {
                    Key: $(this).attr("id"),
                    Value: $(this).val()
                };
                FieldValues.push(FieldValue);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../Handler.ashx?&Action=Save",
            data: JSON.stringify(FieldValues),
            type: "post",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        });
```

But when i tried to deserialize to List of dictionary.

```
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, string>> WebFields = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
WebFields = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsonString);
```

My expected output list is like,

```
  string Key =  WebFields[0].Key
  string Value =  WebFields[0].Value
```

But now it is like each WebField item is like,

```
WebFields[0]  -> [0] -> Key
                 [1]  -> Value
```

How to achieve my expected output ?

Comment: `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` should be `Dictionary<string, string>` Dictionary is essentially a list of `KeyValuePair` so you're making a list of lists, it that what you want?

Comment: @Matt If i change to Dictionary<string, string> getting exception, 'WebFields = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString)' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: @vinothkumar, could you please show your data contains in  `JSON.stringify(FieldValues),`?

Comment: @vinothkumar, means how your `jsonString` look like in back end?

Comment: @er-shoaib                                                                                                        
var jsonString = "[{\"Key\":\"1_1_1_1_1_TXT\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Key\":\"2_TXT\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Key\":\"3_TXT\","Value":\"\"}]"

Comment: @vinothkumar, could you please show me the exception details occurred when you made `List<Dic....>` to only `Dic<>`?

Comment: Thank you all for your support ! I've added new model with key and value properties.

Comment: Please show the json produced as well.

Comment: Sorry all i made confusion here, my intention is to produce dictionary like WebFields[0] -> {"1_TXT" :  "TEST"}. I need to take values based on unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a dictionary server side, try to send a basic POJO.
Instead of:

```
 var FieldValue = {
                Key: $(this).attr("id"),
                Value: $(this).val()
            };
  FieldValues.push(FieldValue);
```

try:

```
 var key = $(this).attr("id");
 var value =$(this).val()
 var fieldValue = { key: value };
 fieldValues.push(fieldValue);
```

A javascript object is represented as a key value pair, thus returning a Dictionary will return a JS object with the key being propname, and value being the value

Comment: it's coming like WebFields[0] -> [0] -> {"Key" :  } Also, If i do like this key will be differnet for each item.

Comment: The key fundamentally *will* be different each time. Try to add a duplicate key in c# to a dictionary and you'll receive an exception.
You are wrapping it as List<Dictionary<string, string>> whilst it should be Dictionary<string, string>. No list

Comment: Thanks your approach. It worked for me with a slight modification,  var key = $(this).attr("id");
 var value =$(this).val();
 FieldValues[key] = value;

Comment: Awesome! That works too (the original mechanism should too but may be casing mismatches), I think your way is a more readable way to do it. If I can give any unsolicited advice, try to stay away from Dictionary<T, T> and JSON.
I tend to create something called CustomKvP class with public string Key and public string Value if I ever need to deal with this type of struct. But 99.99% use your own POCOs